# Call in android studio

Tags: android

I completed my android studio phone call code, but my app doesn't work, when run my code in my cell phone it does't work.

```
String number= phncall.getText().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(("tel"+number)));
startActivity(intent);
```

It throws this exception:

`Unable to peek into adb socket due to error. Closing socket.: Connection reset by peer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may help you

```
Intent dialPhoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:"+phoneNumber));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add the relevant permission to your manifest and implement run time Permission

**Try This Code** 
Add In manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(CustomerSupportActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) CustomerSupportActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 500);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "0000-11-1111"));
                CustomerSupportActivity.this.startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: if problem solve , please make answer accepted and give me points